# Installing numpy with pip (python3) in virtual environment on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, numpy, pip

I am getting this error while installing numpy on python3.4 in ubuntu15.10. I am trying to install numpy in virtual environment.

Just to make it clear, I have installed numpy and pandas on other windows and ubuntu(12.04) systems many times and did never face this kind of problem.

The traceback is:

```
Downloading/unpacking numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.12.0.zip (4.8MB): 4.8MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-2eedq1yh/numpy/setup.py) egg_info for package numpy
    Running from numpy source directory.

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)


    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found
    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
    F2PY Version 2
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    building library "npymath" sources
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize IntelFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifc
    customize LaheyFCompiler
    Could not locate executable lf95
    customize PGroupFCompiler
    Could not locate executable pgfortran
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize NAGFCompiler
    customize VastFCompiler
    customize CompaqFCompiler
    Could not locate executable fort
    customize IntelItaniumFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize PathScaleFCompiler
    Could not locate executable pathf95
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread _configtest.o -o _configtest
    success!
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’
     int exp (void);
         ^
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread _configtest.o -o _configtest
    _configtest.o: In function `main':
    /tmp/pip-build-2eedq1yh/numpy/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    _configtest.o: In function `main':
    /tmp/pip-build-2eedq1yh/numpy/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    failure.
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’
     int exp (void);
         ^
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread _configtest.o -lm -o _configtest
    success!
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c
    building library "npysort" sources
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npysort/quicksort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npysort/mergesort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npysort/heapsort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private/npy_partition.h
      adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private' to include_dirs.
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private/npy_binsearch.h
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npysort/binsearch.c
    None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private/npy_partition.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private/npy_binsearch.h']
    building extension "numpy.core._dummy" sources
    Generating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/include/numpy/config.h
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    success!
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    success!
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c:1:24: fatal error: sys/endian.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    _configtest.c:1:24: fatal error: sys/endian.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    failure.
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    success!
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    success!
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    success!
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    success!
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c: In function ‘main’:
    _configtest.c:5:16: warning: variable ‘test_array’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         static int test_array [1 - 2 * !(((long) (sizeof (npy_check_sizeof_type))) >= 0)];
                    ^
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c: In function ‘main’:
    _configtest.c:5:16: warning: variable ‘test_array’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         static int test_array [1 - 2 * !(((long) (sizeof (npy_check_sizeof_type))) == 4)];
                    ^
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c: In function ‘main’:
    _configtest.c:5:16: warning: variable ‘test_array’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         static int test_array [1 - 2 * !(((long) (sizeof (npy_check_sizeof_type))) >= 0)];
                    ^
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c: In function ‘main’:
    _configtest.c:5:16: warning: variable ‘test_array’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         static int test_array [1 - 2 * !(((long) (sizeof (npy_check_sizeof_type))) == 8)];
                    ^
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    success!
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c: In function ‘main’:
    _configtest.c:5:16: warning: variable ‘test_array’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         static int test_array [1 - 2 * !(((long) (sizeof (npy_check_sizeof_type))) >= 0)];
                    ^
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c: In function ‘main’:
    _configtest.c:5:16: warning: variable ‘test_array’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         static int test_array [1 - 2 * !(((long) (sizeof (npy_check_sizeof_type))) == 8)];
                    ^
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c: In function ‘main’:
    _configtest.c:5:16: warning: variable ‘test_array’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         static int test_array [1 - 2 * !(((long) (sizeof (npy_check_sizeof_type))) >= 0)];
                    ^
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c: In function ‘main’:
    _configtest.c:5:16: warning: variable ‘test_array’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         static int test_array [1 - 2 * !(((long) (sizeof (npy_check_sizeof_type))) == 16)];
                    ^
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c'
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c: In function ‘main’:
    _configtest.c:7:12: error: ‘SIZEOF_LONGDOUBLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         (void) SIZEOF_LONGDOUBLE;
                ^
    _configtest.c:7:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
    _configtest.c: In function â
```

Comment: Seems the message is cut off.  To build numpy from source you usually need a fortran compiler (`apt install gfortran`) and some math libraries (`apt install libblas-dev libatlas-base-dev liblapack-dev`)

Comment: I am installing it with pip. And also, I have installed numpy & pandas on new machines but never had to manually install fortran compiler. What could be the reason?

Comment: Could it be that those machines had a sufficiently new version of pip such that it didn't build from source and installed prebuilt wheels (either windows wheels or manylinux1 wheels)?

Comment: That solved the problem :) Please post your comment as an answer so that i can accept it. Also, I am facing similar problem in pandas installation (using deprecated Numpy API), can it be some similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build numpy from source (you probably don't want to though) you'll need several build dependencies, usually a fortran compiler `apt install gfortran` and some mathy libraries `apt-install libblas-dev libatlas-base-dev liblapack-dev`.

If you're using a sufficiently new version of pip (>=8.1) you'll download prebuilt wheels on linux platforms (via [PEP 513](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/)).  You can upgrade pip using `pip install pip --upgrade`